# Existence of $1$-separated and $(1-\varepsilon)$-dense set in metric spaces

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, mg.metric-geometry, manifolds

Is it know which metric spaces $M$ do have the following property: there is $\varepsilon>0$ and a maximal $1$-separated set which is $(1-\varepsilon)$-dense?

In other words, when does at set $S\subset M$ with the following properties exits?

1. $\rho(x,y)\geq 1$ for all $x,y\in S$ with $x\neq y$
2. For every $x\in M$ there is a $y\in S$ with $\rho(x,y)\leq 1-\varepsilon$.

In particular, we would be interested whether locally compact (uniquely) geodesic metric spaces have this property.

A metric space is geodesic, if for every pair of points $x,y\in M$ there is an isometry $\gamma\colon [0,\rho(x,y)]\to M$ with $\gamma(0)=x$ and $\gamma(\rho(x,y))=y$. It is called uniquely geodesic if $\gamma$ is unique.

Comment: could you give the definition of $1$-separated and $(1-\varepsilon)$-dense ?

Comment: @an_ordinary_mathematician done.

Comment: Perhaps also the definition of the (uniquely) geodesic metric space could be provided?

Comment: @AlekseiKulikov Thank you for the comment! I added the definition.

Comment: @ChristianRemling Maybe the standard symplex $\Delta_d$ (normalized with unit length  edges) is easier than the $d$-cube to work with. Isn't a maximal $1$-separated subset with more than one point necessarily the $0$-skeleton?

Comment: Uh but for the normalized $d$-simplex the best $\epsilon$ is I think  $1-\sqrt{\frac d{2(d+1)}}$ (realized for $x=$ the baricenter), not o(1)

Comment: Actually a much simpler attempt along the same lines is to take a circle of circumference $L<2$, $L\simeq 2$. Since we can put only one point on such a circle, the $\epsilon$ will be very small. It's not clear to me though how to build a space that contains circles with $L$ arbitrarily close to $2$ without the connecting pieces ruining the effect. (Also, such a space would never be *uniquely* geodesic.)